# Android Rotate Matrix

Tags: java, android

I have matrix. This matrix represents array x and y coordinates. For example

```
float[] src = {7,1,7,2,7,3,7,4};
```

I need to rotate this coordinates to 90 degrees.
I use  `android.graphics.Matrix` like this:

```
    float[] src = {7,1,7,2,7,3,7,4};
    float[] dist = new float[8];
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.preRotate(90.0f);
    matrix.mapPoints(dist,src);
```

after operation rotate I have array with next values

```
-1.0    7.0     -2.0    7.0     -3.0    7.0     -4.0    7.0
```

Its is good for area with 360 degrees. 
And how do rotate in area from 0 to 90? I need set up center of circle in this area but how ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `setRotate`, not `preRotate`:

- `setRotate` initializes the matrix as a rotation matrix.
- `preRotate` multiplies the current matrix by a rotation matrix `M' =
  M x R`

Since you called the default constructor your starting with the identity matrix.

Remember matrix multiplication is not commutative.

Comment: setRotate returns the same result :(

Comment: I'm confused, i actually looked at your numbers and rotating the points (7,1), (7,2), (7,3), (7,4) 90 degrees around the origin should result in (7,-1), (7,-2), (7,-3), (7,-4).  Which is what you got.  You example is the correct rotation of these points.

Comment: Why, I did rotation for 90 degrees and my points moved from area 0 -90 to area 90-180. The second area contains positive Y and negative X. So you wrote (7,-1), (7,-2), (7,-3), (7,-4) where first number is X and second is Y. I think this incorrect because area 90 -180 does not contain negative Y.

Comment: Yes, you was correct setRotate(90,x,y) but set rotate with center of rotation ... not only value of angel.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with android, but if you translate after you rotate you can get a rotation around a specific point. Find where your center point would be rotated to, then translate it back to it's original position.

Comment: I think you mean: "If you rotate after you translate you can get a rotation around a specific point"

Comment: @Eyal either works actually, but the translation is different in each case

Comment: you are right. However, I believe that in the translate-rotate-translate approach, the translation parameters are much simpler to compute, right?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Matrix` `preRotate(float degrees, float px, float py)` method [(`preRotate` documenation)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#preRotate(float,%20float,%20float))

This `preRoate(degrees)` is equivalent to `preRotate(degrees, 0, 0)`.